# Outer stroke around png using PHP and Imagemagick

Tags: php, imagemagick, imagick

I'm trying to put a white stroke around the contents of a transparent png. I have successfully done this with the code below, however it applied an inner stroke, so it's actually covering the outer edges of the png and looks bad.

Outer stroke code:

```
   $alpha = clone $overlay;
   $alpha->separateImageChannel(Imagick::CHANNEL_ALPHA);
   $alpha->negateImage(true);
   $alpha_width = $alpha->getImageWidth();
   $alpha_height = $alpha->getImageHeight();
   $alpha->edgeImage(10);
   $alpha->opaquePaintImage("white","white",6500,FALSE);
   $alpha->transparentPaintImage("black",0.0,0,FALSE);
   $overlay->compositeImage($alpha,Imagick::COMPOSITE_DEFAULT,0,0);
```

I tried changing the edge size to negative, hoping it would turn into an outer stroke but it did not.

I also found that there is a morphology method called EdgeOut that does what I want. However, I can't find any info on how to use it in the PHP manual. I tried the following, but I got an error (Undefined class constant 'MORPHOLOGY_EDGEOUT')

```
$alpha->morphology(\Imagick::MORPHOLOGY_EDGEOUT, 2, $kernel);
```

Comment: Whatever your stroke size is, first make the image 2x `$stroke` wider and taller, and then apply the stroke as usual.

Comment: See $canvas->morphology(\Imagick::MORPHOLOGY_EDGE_OUT, 1, $kernel); at https://www.php.net/manual/en/imagick.morphology.php

Comment: @Sammitch That doesn't give you a stroke.

Comment: @fmw42 Thanks! I just missed that underscore. Which is odd that it's there since it's EdgeOut when working from the command line.